# Android stop SoundPool loop across multi activities. Or stop all playing sounds when changing pages

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have only been programming with Android and Java for a few weeks now, trying to make a guitar tuner to tune your guitar by ear. A simple reference tuner. I have used much of this website code to construct it.

How can I make a SoundPool stop when I click to another page/activity.

Currently I have two pages, each with 7 sound buttons. When you click any button it loops indefinitely until you click  another button, then that loops and so on... If I click the button for the next page and then click a new button, the sound from the last page is still playing! rather annoying when you are trying to tune your guitar by ear!

Maybe just a simple stop button to stop the entire SoundPool would be a good idea?

Here is my SoundManager code
        package org.gtdb.guitar_tuners;

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.SoundPool;

    public class SoundManager 
    {
        private Context pContext;
        private SoundPool sndPool;
        private float rate = 1.0f;
        private float masterVolume = 1.0f;
        private float leftVolume = 1.0f;
        private float rightVolume = 1.0f;
        private float balance = 0.5f;

        // Constructor, setup the audio manager and store the app context
        public SoundManager(Context appContext)
        {
          sndPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
          pContext = appContext;
        }

        // Load up a sound and return the id
        public int load(int sound_id)
        {
            return sndPool.load(pContext, sound_id, 1);
        }

        // Play a sound
        public void play(int sound_id)
        {
            sndPool.play(sound_id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 100, -1, rate);     
        }


        // Set volume values based on existing balance value
        public void setVolume(float vol)
        {
            masterVolume = vol;

            if(balance < 1.0f)
            {
                leftVolume = masterVolume;
                rightVolume = masterVolume * balance;
            }
            else
            {
                rightVolume = masterVolume;
                leftVolume = masterVolume * ( 2.0f - balance );
            }

        }

        public void setSpeed(float speed)
        {
            rate = speed;

            // Speed of zero is invalid 
            if(rate < 0.01f)
                rate = 0.01f;

            // Speed has a maximum of 2.0
            if(rate > 2.0f)
                rate = 2.0f;
        }

        public void setBalance(float balVal)
        {
            balance = balVal;

            // Recalculate volume levels
            setVolume(masterVolume);
        }



        // Free ALL the things!
        public void unloadAll()
        {
            sndPool.release();      
        }

    }
```

Here is my Activity code Main.java
package org.gtdb.guitar_tuners;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;        
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.ads.AdView;

    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class Main extends Activity {

        SoundManager snd;
        int string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7;
        OnClickListener buttZonClick;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adMobUnit);

            // Create the adView
            // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
            AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_MRECT, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa");

            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);

            // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            request.setTesting(true);

            adView.loadAd(request);

            // Create an instance of our sound manger
            snd = new SoundManager(getApplicationContext());

            // Load the samples from res/raw
            string1 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe1);
            string2 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe2);
            string3 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe3);
            string4 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe4);
            string5 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe5);
            string6 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbe6);
            string7 = snd.load(R.raw.eadgbestrum);

            /** Tuner Link **/
            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tuner1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Dadgad.class));
                }
            });
            /** Tuner Link **/
            Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tuner2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Daefce.class));


                }
            });

            /** gtdb.org Link **/
            ImageButton b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            b7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse("http://www.gtdb.org/stats/click.php?id=17"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }

        public int count = 0;
        // Button listener assigned in XML layout
        public void clickHandler(View v) {
            int id = v.getId(); // Use the button id to determine which sample
                                // should be played

            switch (id) {
            case R.id.button1:
                    snd.play(1);
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                snd.play(2);
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                snd.play(3);
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                snd.play(4);
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                snd.play(5);
                break;

            case R.id.button6:
                snd.play(6);
                break;

            case R.id.button7:
                snd.play(7);
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                        "Android Guitar Tuner App from Guitar Tunings Database - www.gtdb.org",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Apologies for the code, I might imagine that it's a mess as I am basically a newbie at Java and Android. I have been piecing together from other peoples code and from watching lynda.com videos.

The current version of my tuner is on the market but it has no loop on the sounds so you can go through the pages and listen. but without a loop on it you have to keep pressing the button to tune your guitar! you can see that [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gtdb.guitar_tuners)

Answer (score 0):

Does `Soundpool.stop(int)` work for you? If so, why not just override the `Activity.onPause()` method and put it there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but since I asked the question I have rewritten the layout to house all of the pages on one page, using visibility to hide and show page elements. 

I have just finished and published Version 2 of the app and am considering a fresh rewrite again. I will try Soundpool.stop(int) at that point.

Thanks again for your time.